# Installed Nvidia drivers 384 and screen flickering on dark backgrounds plus low FPS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

So previously I had Nvidia 390.12 drivers installed and wanted to revert to 384.11. I did this with `$ sudo apt install nvidia-384` (after purging `nvidia-*`) and rebooted, only to have things at a 3:4 resolution. I did `$ xrandr` which said it couldn't detect my DVI port:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1920x1080_144.00 (0x27b) 452.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2088 end 2296 total 2672 skew    0 clock 169.35KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1177           clock 143.88Hz
```

Note that I did `cvt 1920 1080 144` before to create a new mode (I have a 144Hz monitor, which was working with the 390 drivers).

Then I did `$ xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080_144.00` and `$ xrandr` again, to get:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
   1920x1080_144.00 143.88
```

Closed the terminal and reopened it, somehow it now shows

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
   1920x1080_144.00 143.88
```

Note that the max went up to 1080p. Tried to set the mode from the display manager GUI and got this.

[image]

Also, just to note, I tried turning off secure boot from my UEFI just in case. No dice.

Eventually I thought to check out monitors.xml and found that the setting came from the "default" section. Changed it to 1920 x 1080 as well as setting the refresh rate, rebooted, and things are finally 1080p. Great, right? Well, now on dark backgrounds, things seem to flicker a bit. Also, I ran `$ xrandr` again:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98    99.93    84.90    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It seems to detect my DVI output now which is great, although I'm not sure why that worked. I rebooted a bunch of times before that so I don't think it was the rebooting. I also installed `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-current` as per what some internet folks said in order to make `$ nvidia-xconfig` work (still can't run `$ nvidia-xconfig`—says "command not found") so that might have changed something.

Anyway, on darker backgrounds (strangely can't really see this on white and middle-grey), the screen visibly flickers like it's quickly getting darker and then back to normal. I then try `$ xrandr -r 144` (because it says I'm still at 60Hz for some reason). Screen goes black as expected, then it goes *ballistic* and starts flashing really dark and then back to normal. It doesn't look like a black screen either, it's more like there's a semi-transparent black overlay on my screen that flashes rapidly. When I say rapidly, I mean *rapidly*. Like, epilepsy-inducing.

Freaking out, I type (without looking at my screen because it's spazzing out) `$ xrandr -r 60` and it goes back to normal, and I can only see mild flickering on darker backgrounds (eg Discord).

I check monitors.xml and, yep, my input has 144 as its refresh rate so I'm not sure what's going on with it defaulting to 60. Then I try to create a new mode with a 144 refresh rate and then set it as the mode for my output. My monitor then says "out of range" in front of a black background. I do a hard shutdown and turn it back on.

Now I decide to test with some games. I start up a game that usually has 144+ FPS (I cap it at 140 so there's no tearing). Now I'm getting **30-45 FPS**. I've used the 384 drivers with this exact setup without issue—although, last time, I did install them with the .run from Nvidia's website rather than from the package manager.

GPU: GTX 1060 6GB

Other Info:

```
$ lspci|grep VGA
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)

$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x67) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
    Identifier: 0x63
    Timestamp:  2118219
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000469e12401010101
        351a010380351e78ea9de5a654549f26
        0d5054b7ef00714f8180814081c08100
        9500b3000101023a801871382d40582c
        4500132b2100001e000000fd0032961e
        a021000a202020202020000000fc0056
        473234380a20202020202020000000ff
        0047434c4d51533133373137340a01c7
        020104008a4d80a070382c4030203500
        132b2100001afe5b80a0703835403020
        3500132b2100001a866f80a070384040
        30203500132b2100001afc7e80887038
        124018203500132b2100001e00000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000bb
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1080 (0x67) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x68) 325.080MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1976 total 2056 skew    0 clock 158.11KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1098           clock 144.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x69) 285.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock 137.26KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1144           clock 119.98Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6a) 235.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock 113.22KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1133           clock  99.93Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6b) 198.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  95.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1124           clock  84.90Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6c) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x6d) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6e) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6f) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x70) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x960 (0x71) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800 (0x72) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x73) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x74) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x75) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x76) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x77) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x78) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x79) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x7a) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x7b) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x7c) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x7d) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x7e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x7f) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x80) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x81) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x82) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x64
    Timestamp:  2118219
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x65
    Timestamp:  2118219
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c03] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:3283]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_304
```

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qnwQP5xJKw/) is the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MMdhBycHVB/) is the output of `apt-cache policy nvidia-\*`.

```
$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-304, 304.137, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Edit: tried reinstalling drivers with David Foerster's instructions and I now have the option to use 390 drivers. I'm gonna try using them instead. Selected the 390.25 drivers and:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c03] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:3283]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_390, nvidia_390_drm
```

[Output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tJgPRgyC4x/) of `$ apt-cache policy nvidia-\*`.

```
$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-390, 390.25, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Edit:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia_390 && lsmod | grep nvidia || dmesg | grep nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_390': No such device
[   15.101755] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   15.101759] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   15.107491] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.113512] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 243
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
[   15.113767] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 243
[   15.327252] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 243
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
[   15.327510] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 243
[30422.212356] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
[30422.212757] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
```

Edit: Okay, so after some searching, I saw that in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, there was `nvidia` being blacklisted. I removed that and rebooted, and when I boot into Ubuntu the screen now starts flashing. I booted from recovery mode which works for some reason, and in recovery mode I don't have the issue anymore. Everything displays normally and I can set it to 144Hz. So I suppose I fixed the titular issue, but now I have to boot from recovery mode. At least I have a workaround now, I suppose?

Comment: Hi, I've added the requested information! Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I've done that and added relevant information to my post (see "Edit:"). I'm still having the exact same issues with the latest drivers though.

Comment: Done that! Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Okay, so I sort of fixed the issue? I'm still having issues but I've found a workaround. I've edited my main post with more information. I suppose it's better to have a fully functional workaround than a semi-functioning normal system.

Comment: Done that! I'll post a new question after doing some troubleshooting as I have some idea as to what this might be. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue with this was that `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` contained `nvidia`. After removing that and rebooting, this issue resolved itself.